# Error printing pdf in OpenGeo Suite client SDK app

Tags: postgis, error, printing, boundless-suite

I am using OpenGeo Suite 3.0.2. I created an app using Client SDK and stored the raster and vector data on postgreSQL/PostGIS.

The print tool is not working, giving error the following error:

> Java.io.IOException: the byte array is not recognized imageformat.

These are the dependencies, I included:

- @require plugins/Print.js
- @require GeoExt.ux/PrintPreview.js
- @require GeoExt/widgets/PrintMapPanel.js
- @require GeoExt/plugins/PrintProviderField.js
- @require GeoExt/plugins/PrintPageField.js
- @require OpenLayers/Control/ScaleLine.js

This is the code I included for print service:

```
{
   ptype: "gxp_print",
   customParams: {outputFilename: 'DAA Map-PDF'},
   printService: "/geoserver/pdf/",
   actionTarget: "map.tbar",
   showButtonText: true
}
```

Comment: Can you show the part of your code that it's failing?

Comment: please add a fuller description of your set up

Comment: I am not able to post here so I edited the Question

Comment: It looks like the error is occurring in GeoServer.  Could you check the layer in the GeoServer layer preview?  Take a look in the GeoServer logs for a more complete error message and supporting information (INFO and WARN messages preceding the error)

Comment: Also, how exactly did you load the data into PostGIS and how do you set up the layer in GeoServer?

Comment: I used PostGIS shapefile and dbf loader to load the vector data and PostGIS raster plugin to load the raster data...
then I used Image mosaic JDBC plugin to publish raster data on geoserver and vector data thorugh PostGIS database store.
Layers are working fine in the Goeserver layer preview..

Comment: **This is the error message.**

2013-06-05 17:19:49,260 INFO [geoserver.flow] - Control flow installed, but no rules configured in controlflow.properties
2013-06-05 17:19:50,292 WARN [mortbay.log] - !ContinuationFilter installed
2013-06-05 17:19:53,352 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2013-06-05 17:19:53,354 INFO [geoserver.flow] - Control flow installed, but no rules configured in controlflow.properties
2013-06-05 17:19:53,443 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2013-06-05 17:19:53,445 ERROR [geoserver.ows] -

Comment: That's a completely different message  look in the log for where the specific "Java.io.IOException" occurs.  Also, improve the question by adding any relevant additional information to the question itself, not by posting it in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You must resolve the dependencies, so, you need to activate the printing module in geoserver.
Please, follow the steps in http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/printing/